# Function that takes name of textBox as argument

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make a function for Windows Forms like:

```
private void do(textBox_name, string text)
{
     textBox_name.Text=text.toString();
}
```

The function should take name of `textBox` as an argument, then write text to right textBox.

But I don't know how can I send properly which textBox should be used.

At this moment I have done it in "if statement", but adding new elements is scripting it again and again because I have to write

`textBox1.Text=text.toString();` then `textBox2.Text=text.toString();`

for every textBox that takes a lot of time. Also, I know I can do it with switches, like this:

```
switch(ID)
    case 1:
        textBox1.Text=text.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        textBox2.Text=text.toString();
```

But I guess there is a way to do one function for every textBox.

Comment: You could use the form's `FindControl` method.

Comment: But why would you pass the control's name instead of it's reference in the first place?

Comment: You forgot to specify what type `textBox_name` is. String? What code would call this method? Where does `ID` come from? You're hiding something :)

Comment: Seems more like XY problem. Did you create your textboxes dynamically? Can you show a complete sample of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have one question - why are you invoking `ToString()` method on a `string`? It is completely unnecessary.

Your function should look like:

```
private void do(TextBox tb, string text)
{
    tb.Text = text;
}
```

If you work with `double`s, then it will differ slightly:

```
private void do(TextBox tb, double number) //use meaningful names, "text" for double is poor choice
{
    tb.Text = number.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is a great commend but does not provide an answer to the question...

Comment: Id want my 45 wasted printable characters back :)

Comment: Yes, you're right but i work on doubles. Just here i wrote wrong type :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think it doesn't fit as comment, it could be a comment, but without details.

Comment: I'm in middle of changing names of some variables, so some of them still have names that are not meaningful :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome again. Problem has been solved, it was easy so i'm really embarassed how long i was looking for solving problem. I didn't knew that i can send to function parameter of TextBox.
Now it looks like

`private void write(TextBox tbox, string text)
{
tbox.Text=text;
}`